# PHP PDO - Dados da consulta MySQL não aparecem na tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

O que estou fazendo de errado nesse script?

Faço uma consulta no banco para retornar todos os dados da tabela `curso` e mostrar os nomes dos mesmos na tabela, mas não está funcionando.

Além disso essa parte do código está sendo mostrada na página:

```
(prepare("SELECT * FROM curso"); if($consulta->execute()){ ?>
fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ ?> '.$dados->idCursoLi . ''; echo ''; echo ''; } }?>
'.$dados->nomeCursoLi . '
```

Meu código:

```html
<?php


  require '../conexao/conexao_BD.php';
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Painel</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="../css/styles-Painel.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo">
              <h1><a>Painel do Administrador</a></h1>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
              <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Minha Conta<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInUp">
                      <li><a href="logout.php">Sair</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
            <ul class="nav">
              <!-- Main menu -->
              <li class="current"><a href="painel.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
              <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Administrador
                  <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Sub menu -->
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="cadastrarAdm.html">Cadastrar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Editar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Remover</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Curso
                  <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Sub menu -->
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="cadastrarCurso.html">Cadastrar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Editar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Remover</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>




      <div class="container">
        <table class="table-bordered">

          <h2>Cursos cadastrados</h2>

          <?php $consulta = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM curso");

              if($consulta->execute()){ ?>


          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Curso</th>
                <th>Excluir</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php while($dados = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ ?>

            <tr>
              <?php echo '<td>'.$dados->idCursoLi . '</td>';
                                  echo '<td>'.$dados->nomeCursoLi . '</td>'; 
                                  echo '<td><a href="deletarCurso.php?id='.$dados->idCursoLi.'"><img src="delete.png" alt="Excluir curso" height="42" width="42"></a></td>';

                                  } }?>

            </tr>


          </table>


      </div>



      <footer>
        <div class="container">

          <div class="copy text-center">
            Copyright(@) <a href="inove.html">Inove.</a> Desenvolvido por: <a target="blank_" href="http://tecnosystemej.com/site/">Tecno System</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </footer>

      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários erros no seu código, mas tomei como objetivo a solução do seu erro:

> PHP PDO - dados oriundo do banco MySQL não aparece na tabela

Estrutura da tabela `curso` (Criei para fins de teste):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `curso` (
    `idCursoLi` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nomeCursoLi` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci` NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `curso` (`nomeCursoLi`) VALUES ('foo'), ('bar'), ('fubá'), ('canjica'), ('angu');
```

Código da página (Somente a tabela):

```
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <h2>Cursos cadastrados</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php

                $conexaoMySQL = new PDO(
                                'mysql:host='.'meu_host'.
                                ';dbname='.'meu_banco',
                                'meu_usuario',
                                'minha_senha',
                                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );

                $stmt = $conexaoMySQL -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `curso`;");
                if( $stmt -> execute() )
                {
                    $res = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                    foreach($res as $curso)
                    { ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $curso -> idCursoLi; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $curso -> nomeCursoLi; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="deletarCurso.php?id=<?= $curso -> idCursoLi; ?>"><img src="delete.png" alt="Excluir curso" height="42" width="42"></a></td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: Lembre-se de reconfigurar a conexão *PDO* com o banco de dados e implementar o tratamento dos erros (Exceções)!

Você deve comparar meu código com o seu para fins didáticos.

Comment: Oi, valeu! Eu consegui ajeitar, tinha duas tags <table>, apaguei e foi! Mas essa forma que vc fez usando Expression Language é uma boa opção p quem não quiser mesclar HTML cm PHP como eu fiz.